# What is the appropriate way to replace local: keyword with a path?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, namespaces

### Problem

Take the following code snippet:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TestViewModel}">
        <local:TestView></local:TestView>
</DataTemplate>
```

`local:` is defined like this:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Palette_Packing"
```

Now, `TestViewModel` is in a subfolder, with corresponding namespace `Palette_Packing.ViewModels`.
Obviously, `local:` refers to a different namespace, where `TestViewModel` ist not found.

How do I replace `local:` with the appropriate path to my `TestViewModel`?

### What I have tried so far

Of course I tried the following:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Palette_Packing.ViewModels.TestViewModel}">
        <Palette_Packing.Views.TestView></Palette_Packing.Views.TestView>
</DataTemplate>
```

This however yields an error about unsupported nested types.

Setting the class `TestViewModel` to `public` does also not resolve the issue.

### Disclaimer

The code snippets show a ViewModel and a View, the problem exists for both. For clarity's sake I only asked about the ViewModel.

Also, if ViewModel and View are moved from their subfolder to the main directory, `local:` works fine, as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare another namespace

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Palette_Packing.ViewModels"
```

Then write

```
DataType="{x:Type vm:TestViewModel}"
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working! Just for clarification: Can I consider this good practice (as in "It comes in very handy and I will use it quite often.") or is this just a quick fix? Point being, I want to get better and understand if I made a mistake that can only be resolved by some quick-and-dirty fix.

Comment: This is the only way to declare and use a CLR namespace in XAML.

Comment: @pat3d3r, `xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Palette_Packing.ViewModels"` in xaml is the same as `using Palette_Packing.ViewModels` in c# (.cs). (or rather `using vm = Palette_Packing.ViewModels`). a good practice is to declare only those namespace you need and keep code clean, it is difficult to messup something here.